# Adobe XD: Creating 2 sliders on the same artboard

Tags: adobe-xd, prototyping, interaction

I have two sliders with three cards each on an artboard, they both work great by themselves but is there a way to interact with them both without creating 2*3 new artboards?

Meaning, could I use auto-animation in a more performing way than by creating three artboards per slider?

Comment: hello and welcome! I've also tried to do same but it seems XD doesn't have any option for micro interaction on same artboard. Maybe in future they might add child animations but for now it doesn't seems to be possible as far as I know.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your input, such a shame that they don't allow this option ! I'll try to see if there is a feature request in the adobe community :)

Answer (score 1):

**In 2020!**

This is now available using **components and states**, you no longer require multiple artboards to perform micro-interactions as seen in the images below.

You can create a component, add multiple variations (states) to it, and wire it to mimic real-world user behaviour (without having to copy your components multiple times).

Having components with states also makes it easier to manage your assets and to create interactive design systems.

In this image is a demonstration of interactions possible using a component and different states:

[image: Art board]

and here is the output, an image showing the preview of our artboard:

[image: preview image]

For further information check out Adobe XD's documentation on [components and states](https://helpx.adobe.com/xd/help/create-component-states.html) here's a handy tutorial you can follow for [components and states](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLHjwuoik-ep1PW3Dh29lgnN8X2VSBYEwt)